# IP problems when connection tru external ip

Tags: dd-wrt, ubuntu-server

As of know I get 192.168.1.1 as IP when I connect to myserver.com (my server), is there any way this can be changed so I get my external IP instead?

I need my external IP when I connect to my direct connect hub, or else I will get "You cannot connect to an external IP because you are in LAN".

I use Ubuntu server as OS and Verlihub as DChub. Maybe there is a change in iptables I can do on Ubuntu or dd-wrt?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your domain. Who did you register your actual domain through?

Comment: This is not an issue with my domain. Same thing happend if I connect to my external IP address.

Comment: may  be possible to make anything from your lan to your external ip route to your internal ip. but out of interest, why can't you just connect from your lan to your lan with your internal ip like you're supposed to?

Comment: Read the seconds paragraph and you'll know why.

Comment: @Marwelln oh so perhaps not really a routing thing you need in the manner i thought anyhow. 'cos routing doesn't change an ip. a web  proxy is worth trying, but using a public one may have security issues so don't do user/pass on it  unless you know it's secure. so try that.. but ideal would be a local solution that you control. what's the make and model of your hub? I ask 'cos it may help find stuff related to that problem.

Comment: This problem was specific to the dchubb software and is now fixed.